# When are ARM templates used in the deployment process?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm learning about ARM templates in Azure. So far I've done a few tests with deploying some infrastructure through the PowerShell Azure module. With the goal of automation in mind, I'm wondering when/how are ARM templates used in the deployment process? Since they are used for creating infrastructure, are they mostly used just initially to setup environments consistently? Or are they continuously used in an automated fashion?

Comment: In the case of Azure Data Factory for example, ARM templates are also used to deploy code (pipelines)

Comment: They're continually used. The idea is that the ARM templates for the application are first-class members of the project and live right alongside the application code. As the application evolves, the ARM templates will also evolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel mentions ARM templates are used to not only deploy infrastructure, but to maintain it. So when you start creating the app you only need a vm and a storage account, later on you add another vm and load balancer. then you add cosmos db. and so on.

Another good reason to use ARM templates - creating dev\test\prod environments that mimic each other and maintaining them (so that there is no configuration drift).

Comment: Okay, so as you add more resources and push the ARM template after making changes like adding a new resource, the prior resources aren't affected correct?

Comment: Also, would it be common to write a task in a CI pipeline to deploy the arm template every time? This way if there are changes, it will get updated, and if not, it won't make a difference? Just trying to see how I can fit this in to the deployment cycle to properly automate it.

Comment: they will be affected if their state changed. they will get coerced to the version defined in the template. So any changes implemented outside of the template will get lost (which is a good thing). Help maintain proper state. Usually - yes, you'd have a build or build\release that would run the template on every commit or when the template had changes